# netCDF4-python-generated file poorly displayed in Panoply

Tags: python, visualization, netcdf

I'm creating netCDF-files with pre-defined data types for the variables and attributes, and I'm using netCDF4 and python for this.

My minimal example looks like this:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

root_grp = Dataset("test_single_band.nc" ,'w',format = 'NETCDF4') 
data_grp = root_grp.createGroup("data") 
data_grp.createDimension("num_pixels", 3264) 
data_grp.createDimension("num_lines", None)

measurement_data_grp = data_grp.createGroup("measurement_data")
measurement_data_grp.createVariable("band", "u2",  \ 
("num_pixels","num_lines"), fill_value = np.uint16(8191)) 

measurement_data_grp["band"].long_name = "radiances"
measurement_data_grp["band"].units = "W m-2 sr-1 um-1"
measurement_data_grp["band"].scale_factor = np.float(0.085006105) 
measurement_data_grp["band"].add_offset = np.float(7.61) 
measurement_data_grp["band"].valid_min = np.uint16(0) 
measurement_data_grp["band"].valid_max = np.uint16(8190)

data_max = 4830.
data_min = 30.
data = data_max*np.random.random((3264,3800)) +  data_min

target = root_grp["data/measurement_data/band"]
target[:] = data.astype(target.dtype)

root_grp.close()
```

And my issue is as follows: The file created by this script is displayed weirdly by Panoply:

[Erroneous plot by Panoply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CecGt.png)

i.e. many values are displayed as if being `NaN` or larger than `valid_max`, which they are not by construction. It should rather look like this:

[Correct plot by Panoply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhBvM.jpg)

Panoply displays the data correctly if I leave out the definition of `valid_max`, or if `valid_max` is set to a floating point data type. Using `valid_range` instead doesn't change anything.

Any pointers to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generates random data values between 30 and 4860, but since you have specified a `scale_factor` and `add_offset`, the values will be stored as packed data. So in this case the values written to the file will be `int`s between 263 [= (30 - 7.61) / 0.085006105] and 57082 [= (4860 - 7.61) / 0.085006105].

Where the problem lies is that the convention when using packed data in a netCDF file in conjunction with `valid_min` and `valid_max` specifications is that the min and max must be specified in terms of the packed values rather than the unpacked values. Since you specified a valid_max of 8190, then any value which packed as an `int` between 8190 and 57082 will be treated as invalid when unpacked by software following standard netCDF conventions.

See:

http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/build/ch08.html#packed-data

http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/build/ch02s05.html#missing-data

Comment: Yes: The `netCDF4` module does packing of the values automatically. Thanks!